# How can I put certain json values into a JS Arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops

I have a JSON File that contains the following:

```
{
    "captions": {
        "1": 
            {"startTime":1, "endTime":5, "german":"Dies ist JSON Text Nr. 1.", "english":"This is JSON Text No. 1."},
        "2": 
            {"startTime":7, "endTime":12, "german":"Dies ist JSON Text Nr. 2.", "english":"This is JSON Text No. 2."},
        "3": 
            {"startTime":15, "endTime":20, "german":"Dies ist JSON Text Nr. 3.", "english":"This is JSON Text No. 3."} 
    }
}
```

Now I want to import the data to a JavaScript file and add all the startTimes to one Array, all the endTimes to another Array and so on. 
I've tried the following, which didn't workout.

```
var arrStart=new Array();
var arrStop=new Array();
var arrGerman=new Array();
var arrEnglish=new Array();
var jsonFile ={};


var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    jsonFile = JSON.parse(this.responseText);  
    for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
        arrStart.push(jsonFile.captions['i'].startTime);
        arrStop.push(jsonFile.captions['i'].stopTime);
        arrEnglish.push(jsonFile.captions['i'].english);
        arrGerman.push(jsonFile.captions['i'].german);  
    }
    };
}

xmlhttp.open("GET", "captions.json", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: You are not using your index correctly. You are trying to access to property `i` of your array, when you really want to acces the value that is contains in the variable `i` ( in this case, the current index (0,1,2,3 ...)).  You might want to try something like this. `arrStart.push(jsonFile.captions[i].startTime);`

Comment: Do you have control over the structure of the data in the file? Seems like it would be easier to just have an array rather than an object with faux-numeric indexes...

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem here is because you are trying to get the ith element of the array as

```
captions['i']
```

when you should be getting

```
captions[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this simple script:

```js
var json = {
    "captions": {
        "1":
            { "startTime": 1, "endTime": 5, "german": "Dies ist JSON Text Nr. 1.", "english": "This is JSON Text No. 1." },
        "2":
            { "startTime": 7, "endTime": 12, "german": "Dies ist JSON Text Nr. 2.", "english": "This is JSON Text No. 2." },
        "3":
            { "startTime": 15, "endTime": 20, "german": "Dies ist JSON Text Nr. 3.", "english": "This is JSON Text No. 3." }
    }
};

var array = [];

for (var i = 1; i < Object.keys(json.captions).length+1; i++) {
    if (json.captions[i].startTime) {
        array.push(json.captions[i].startTime);
    }
}

console.log(array);
```

It goes through every item which contains "startTime" in it, and pushes the value to an array.